# Working with particular lines when using a piece table

Tags: c, data-structures, rendering, text-editor

So I've implemented a text editor the "normal" way (just an array of arrays), but now I am trying to do so using a piece table. Implementing the data structure seems straightforward, but it's unclear to me how to translate actions the user takes in the GUI over to the table without stupidly reading through the entire file. Here is my piece-table definition:

```
typedef struct piece {
    int start;
    int length; 
    char *buffer;
} piece;

typedef struct piece_table {
    char *file_buffer;
    int file_buffer_size;
    char *add_buffer;
    int add_buffer_size; 
    piece *pieces;
} piece_table;
```

My main problem is not knowing what line number some random bit of text is in. For example, let's say someone who has just opened the file tells the editor to "Jump to line 10,000". Doing this in my current text editor is constant time, since I can just index the line in question. But for a piece table approach, it would seem I have to search through every character of the text, counting newline characters until I get to 10,000. Nothing about the actual line count is stored at the data structure level, which seems unfortunate.

I considered adding a special line transition piece to the table, but that fragments things more than necessary. I don't have a lot of other ideas, and am wondering how this is actually done in practice when one works with piece tables.

TL;DR How do I quickly determine what line a particular bit of text is at in my piece table?

Comment: Just after opening the file, you will always have to scan through the file to get to a particular line, unless you store line offsets somewhere on disk as well.

Comment: Are you free to modify the `struct` definitions and add new ones?

Comment: Yeah, I can do whatever I want. This isn't homework, just a for fun project. I get that there will have to be some initial scan of the file, I guess I'm wondering what people usually store to make jumping between lines easy. I haven't seen anything about this in any of the readings about people using piece tables for text editing.

Comment: You could look at how `emacs` does it. I don't know what it does now - I last looked at the C code for version 17.